On post back, aspx DataView.Table causes error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I have an aspx webpage with a Grid View displaying data with subtotal rows. This page runs fine when the page first loads.
The code with an error is using a Grid View On Row Created event to calculate and insert column subtotal rows.
The error comes after changing a dropdown control with Auto Post Back, which is used in the Grid View data source as a parameter.
The post back error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
This error points to the code: Dim dt As DataTable line below.
Code:
    Protected Sub OnRowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        subTotal = 0
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            **Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).DataView.Table**

The example code for doing subtotals comes from this page:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/838/Display-SubTotal-and-Grand-Total-in-ASPNet-GridView/
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried to bind the GridView in the pageload event during post back, but still receive the same error.

So have you used the debugger to see what type e.Row.DataItem has?

When running the first time, the DataItem is: System.Data.DataRowView. On post back, the DataItem is lost/missing.

Yes, because the DataSource is not persisted by default in ASP.NET(HTTP is stateless). Why you need to do this logic on every postback? You should not need it in RowCreated, what you are trying to do? You can access each cell via for example e.Row.Cells[0].Text

I tried e.Row.Cell[0].Text, and it has null/nothing. However, the OnRowCreated event still fires. This is what I don't understand. As to they why, that is defined in the link I provided. The RowCreated event handles calculating and inserting a sub-total row. The paraemter changes what is displayed, and has to be sent back as a query filter. Without using this logic the GridView is displayed correctly, but without sub-totals.

OnRowCreated fires on every postback(as opposed to the OnRowDataBound, which fires only after DataBind, note in your code the If Not IsPostBack Then BindGrid()).  Use the debugger to inspect the cells of the row, maybe it's not e.Row.Cells[0].Text, do you use TemplateFields? Then you can use the name of the control, for example e.Row.FindControl("Name"). You need to provide the aspx, then we can help better.
